# Why is this returning NaN instead of a number?

Tags: javascript

JavaScript noob here...

I'm trying to loop through an array and add the values together. This is what I have:

```
var totalXyz;
var arrayLength = data.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    totalXyz += parseInt(data[i]["xyz"]);
}
alert(totalXyz);
```

That alert returns NaN instead of the total number. What am I doing wrong? I've already checked that the data array contains the numbers I want to add. Just need to add them now.

Thanks!

Comment: Make sure that all data[i]['xyz'] exist and has valid number/ string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `totalXyz` to be a number to start with:

```
var totalXyz = 0;
```

In your code you didn't initialise it, so it was `undefined`, and `undefined` plus any number gives you `NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initially assign the numeric value of `totalXyz` before doing addition.

So this:

```
var totalXyz;
totalXyz += parseInt(data[i]["xyz"]);
```

is analogous to:

```
totalXyz = undefined + parseInt(data[i]["xyz"]);
```

Which yields `NaN` because `undefined` + number = `NaN`

You need to initialize the numeric value of `totalXyz` before doing the calculation.